# Javascript function not working when called in HTML button. But when I simply run the code of the function on it's own, it works

Tags: javascript, html, function, web3js

I'm working on a project where I have written quite a few functions. When I run just the code that's in them (no function) it works. But when I plug the code into a function and call that function from an HTML button. It throws an error.

Here is the code for my button:

`<button id="send" onclick="generateKeyPair()">Generate Random Key Pair</button>`

And here is the code for the `generateKeyPair()` function:

```
function generateKeyPair() {
    var keyPair = web3.eth.accounts.create();
    document.getElementById('privateKey').innerHTML = keyPair.privateKey;
    document.getElementById('generatedAddress').innerHTML = keyPair.address;
}
```

Finally, here is the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: generateKeyPair is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

If this is in anyway helpful, I am using some packages, but all things I have used fine before.

Comment: do you have your script in a different file?

Comment: @seriously Nope! It's in the same file. My bad for not clarifying

Comment: seems like an scope issue, did you declare that function inside of something? @ZacharyBaker

Comment: @jhonny just in my main script tag. ill do some more research on scope issue though. Thank you!

Comment: yeah what @jhonny might be a possible cause, plus check that the script is actually being loaded to be accessed by DOM. try doing something line on load alert just to see js is actually running

Comment: also if is possible you could add an event listener ```button.addEventListener("onclick",generateKeypair())``` @ZacharyBaker, that way you wouldn't have a problem with the scope, but if you do that you have to remember to unmount the event listener

Comment: Please create a [mcve], using the snippet tool of choice (SO snippet, jsfiddle, codesanbdox.io, etc...). Once we see the code in action, we'll be able to tell you exactly why it's not working. From what you've posted you're asking for guesswork, which is not helpful for anyone, including yourself. As you can see, the code you posted [works](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/nxj83oLt/).